# calculate the limit of the following function.

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{5x - e^{2x} + 1}{3x + 3e^{4x} - 3}$$

For some reason I can't find the trick to solve this.
Tried a lot but it always come to a place where its $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: Do you know about equivalent ?

Comment: Have you tried L'hopital's rule?

Comment: never heard of it unfortunatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'hopitals Theorem:

for $ \lim_{x\to a} $ $ \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} $ , if $ \lim_{x\to a} $ $ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ =$ \frac 00 $ or $ \lim_{x\to a} $ $ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ = $ \frac{-\infty}{-\infty} $  or $ \lim_{x\to a} $ $ \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} $ = $ \frac{\infty}{\infty} $

then $ \lim_{x\to a} $ $ \frac {f(x)}{g(x)} $ = $ \lim_{x\to a} $ $ \frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)} $

in your case you have a=0.

$ \lim_{x\to 0} $ = $ \frac{5*0 -e^{2*0} +1}{3*0+3e^{4*0} -3} $ = $ \frac 00 $

so as you can see you can use L'hopitals Theorem here, what it basically says is that if you get $ \frac 00 $ or $ \frac{ +-\infty}{+-\infty} $ when plugging the limit into the function, you can then differentiate the numerator and denominator separativly and get a new function

$ f(x)= 5x - e^{2x} +1 $ numerator of original function

$\frac{d}{dx} $f(x) = $5 -2e^{2x} = f'(x)$ new numerator

$ g(x)= 3x +3e^{4x} -3 $ denominator of original function

$\frac{d}{dx} $g(x) = $ 3+ 12e^{4x} =g'(x)$ new denominator

this gives you: $ \lim_{x\to 0} $  $\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} $ = $ \lim_{x\to 0} $ $ \frac{5-2e^{2x}}{3+12e^{4x}} $ = $ \frac{5-2e^{2*0}}{3+12e^{4*0}} = \frac {3}{15}= \frac {1}{5} $ and this is the answer

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: Multiply and divide by $x$; can you think of a good way to interpret the different parts of:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{5x - e^{2x} + 1}{x} \left(\frac{3x + 3e^{4x} - 3}{x}\right)^{-1}$$

Also, a note on terminology: This is not a rational function, since neither the numerator nor denominator are polynomials.

Comment: Thanks but not really sure how i should proceed from here.

Comment: @NotSure Are there any calculus concepts you've seen other than just plain limits? Do you know of any contexts in which limits are actually applied?

Comment: Yes, i tried to mutiply and divide by x but i still get 0/0 here.

Comment: @NotSure Do you recognize the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} (f(x) - f(0)) / x$ as something special?

Comment: Can't say that i do

Comment: @NotSure Do you know what a derivative is?

Comment: No, i guess we didn't reach that part yet in my calculus course.

Comment: @NotSure I see; in that case, my answer is likely to be completely unhelpful. Are there any other techniques you know for computing limits? In what context did you find this problem?

Comment: Just learned about the number e and learned some tricks to calculate the kinds of limits where the answer is not right in front of us, for example when it is 0/0 so we need to do these tricks, when it's infinity / infinity and such. We sometimes multyply and divide by the some number if it can help, we learned you should divide the higest number in the denumnator in every other number to make things more simple etc.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{5x-e^{2x}+1}{3x+3e^{4x}-3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1-e^{2x}}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}+\frac{5x}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{2x}}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}+5\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{2x}}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}+5\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(x\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(-3+3e^{4x}+3x\right)}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{2x}}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}+5\left(\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{3+12e^{4x}}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{2x}}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}+5\left(\frac{1}{3+12e^{4\cdot 0}}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{2x}}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}+5\left(\frac{1}{15}\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{2x}}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}+\frac{5}{15}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1-e^{2x}}{-3+3e^{4x}+3x}+\frac{1}{3}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(1-e^{2x}\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(-3+3e^{4x}+3x\right)}+\frac{1}{3}=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}-\frac{2e^{2x}}{3(1+4e^{4x})}+\frac{1}{3}=$$
$$-\frac{2e^{2\cdot 0}}{3(1+4e^{4\cdot 0})}+\frac{1}{3}=$$
$$-\frac{2}{15}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{5}$$